# How to get alternative records from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i have table likes this

[image]

I need something like this 
[image]

How to this. Is there any way in query it self or using php ..

I tried orderby rand in mysql but i won't work in my case.

And i think there is only one why through php . Please suggest me some idea how to do this.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason, why do you want like this kind of ordering ?

Comment: What determines that product 4 comes after 1 and not product 5? and that product 2 comes after 4 and not product 3? - There lies your answer.

Comment: @krishna In my view page i want show alternate brands in gird view.

Comment: @paPhid There is not determination  which comes first . but i need somthing like   alternate brands.

Comment: @eggyal around 7 brands.

Comment: What if there are more than two brands in the table?  What if the brands have different numbers of products?  How should the output be displayed in such cases?  Simple 1-2-1-2 alternation will not work.

Comment: @eggyal It should be alternate any thing 1-2-3-1-2-3 or 1-2-1-3-2 any way.

Comment: But what about if each brand has different number of products?  Suppose, for example, that brand 1 has two products and brand 2 has a hundred products?  What then?

Answer (score 0):

In mySql, assuming the table name 'products', the following query gives the result.

```
select a.* from products a ,  products b where a.product_id >= b.product_id and a.brand = b.brand group by a.product_id order by count(b.product_id) , a.product_id;
```

The result is

```
+------------+---------+------+-------+
| product_id | name    | etc  | brand |
+------------+---------+------+-------+
|          1 | sample1 | etc  |     1 |
|          4 | sample4 | etc  |     2 |
|          2 | sample2 | etc  |     1 |
|          5 | sample5 | etc  |     2 |
|          3 | sample3 | etc  |     1 |
|          6 | sample6 | etc  |     2 |
+------------+---------+------+-------+
```